# Select2 behind dialog opened with HTML5 .showmodal()

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2-4

Select2 open select list behind dialog modal window. Chrome 49.

```
<dialog id="hello" class="alert">
    <div style="padding:10px">
        Imagine some great content here.
    </div>
    <div class="linksTable">
      <select name="wpmse_options[social_list]" id="mse_social_list" class="input-block-level wpmse_select2" required>
       </select>

    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="toolbar-actions">
            <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
</dialog>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/memoris/f0sma9tf/6/